# Poetry new does not create a python test

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have googled this question but it is more basic than any of the results.
I am reading a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/dependency-management-python-poetry/) on Poetry and it says that when I do

```
poetry new rp-poetry
```

I should get a `test_rp_poetry.py`

However I do not get that python file.
I also noticed that different than what the tutorial says, the `__init__.py` files are empty

Has the behavior of poetry changed lately?

Comment: Did you read https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#new? That says what it's expected to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, but the question is, has the behaviour changed from before? Meaning, was it supposed to do different in the past? (therefore the info on that tutorial)

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/history/

Comment: @KansaiRobot Yes, the behaviour was changed in Apr 2021: see [this commit](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/commit/85f922dfddb8d8e61408b5d8e53f3bffb6beb2b3). Note that [your tutorial](https://realpython.com/dependency-management-python-poetry/#use-an-existing-requirementstxt-file) uses Python-3.9, which was originally released in 2020.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you! That was very useful! I would like to put this as an answer. Can I do it? or would you prefer to do it yourself? Again thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour was changed in Apr 2021: see [this commit](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/commit/85f922dfddb8d8e61408b5d8e53f3bffb6beb2b3). Note that [your tutorial](https://realpython.com/dependency-management-python-poetry/#use-an-existing-requirementstxt-file) uses Python-3.9, which was originally released in 2020. You should therefore consult [the latest poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#new) in conjunction with the tutorial.